# It is possible to create a decorator to define the schema in the typeorm entity

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I need to define the schema to be used by the Application Entity according to user logged in the system.

My idea was to create some kind of decorator to use as a value in the schema property in the entity.

**Exemple:**

```
@Entity({name: 'teste', schema: @Schema()})
export class TesteEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  nome: string;

}
```

In this entity what represents the value of the schema is the decorator @schema.

But using custom decorators featured in the nestjs documentation didn't help me, if anyone has any ideas on how I can develop this or something better.

I'm using

nodejs
nestjs
typeorm

Comment: I'm sure why you would want to define 2 schema? What are you trying to achieve? Like are you trying to access to definition of id and nome somewhere in your application?

Comment: The system will have an interceptor that will go through the user id "which is my client" I will get what is your database schema

Comment: so each user will have a different database schema?

Comment: I am building a multi tenant application so a user is a customer.  Through his login I will know which is the client.  So I have one schema per client Reference of what I want https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4786

Comment: I would suggest you write a middleware that will identify the active tenant based on url or some other way. With this middleware you can attach the schema id on the request object, for example request.schemaId = 'acme'. Then you could write a custom decorator:

`export const Schema = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
  return req.schemaId;
});`

And with this decorator you can now "inject" this information into whatever method you wish:

`async getProducts(@Schema schemaId)`

Comment: @binici Very good idea. But if I inject this decorator into a controller method for example getProducts (Schema schemaId) I could not define the schema of a repository injected into the constructor for example InjectRepository (TestEntity) private readonly repositoryTest: Repository <TesteEntity>